# JaxB Marshaling in camel

Tags: jaxb, apache-camel, marshalling

I am new to Apache camel and Jax b concept in java.
I have a list of java objects in a camel queue. I want to Marshall it to an xml with Javs DSL(without using spring).
Could any one guide me to do that?

I have the following POJO class

```
public class MyPojo {
private int groupId;
private int memberId;
private String details;
public int getgroupId() {
    return groupId;
}
public void setgroupId(int groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
}
public int getMemberId() {
    return memberId;
}
public void setMemberId(int memberId) {
    this.memberId = memberId;
}
public String getdetails() {
    return details;
}
public void setdetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}}
```

following is my camel code for jaxb implementation

```
JaxbDataFormat jaxbMarshal = new JaxbDataFormat();
    jaxbMarshal.setContextPath("com.test");
    jaxbMarshal.setPartClass("com.test.MyPojo");

from("direct:javaObjects") //this direct having the list of MYPojo Objects
    .marshal(jaxbMarshal)
     .to("src/output");
```

I am getting below exception(I added maven dependency for jaxb in classpath)

```
Failed to create route route4 at: >>> Marshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JaxbDataFormat@3feb2dda] <<< in route: Route(route4)[[From[direct:javaObjects]] -> [Marshal[org.apa... because of Data format 'jaxb' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath
```

Comment: Are you have the dependency of camel-jaxb component in the classpath of your application ?

Comment: Yes you need to add camel-jaxb to the classpath, and also add JAXB annotations to your POJO class, and add the `jaxb.index` file as well. You can search the internet what `jaxb.index` file is.

Comment: Thanks @ClausIbsen. I have annotaed and its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the jaxb.index file(new->File from eclipse). the content of the file should be annotation class name

In our case it should be
        **MyPojo**

and its needs to be placed in context path. in our case it should be placed in
        **com.test** location

and the annotated Pojo class is

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
 public class MyPojo {
@XmlElement
private int groupId;
@XmlElement
private int memberId;
@XmlElement
private String details;
public int getgroupId() {
    return groupId;
}
public void setgroupId(int groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
}
public int getMemberId() {
    return memberId;
}
public void setMemberId(int memberId) {
    this.memberId = memberId;
}
public String getdetails() {
    return details;
}
public void setdetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your pojo with some annotations:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="MY-POJO")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"groupId", "memberId", "details"})
public class MyPojo {
@XmlElement(name = "groupId")
private int groupId;
@XmlElement(name = "memberId")
private int memberId;
@XmlElement(name = "details")
private String details;
public int getgroupId() {
    return groupId;
}
public void setgroupId(int groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
}
public int getMemberId() {
    return memberId;
}
public void setMemberId(int memberId) {
    this.memberId = memberId;
}
public String getdetails() {
    return details;
}
public void setdetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}}
```